# SQL: how to get the count and rate of times the same item was exposed by the same user within two hours of clicking on an item

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hiveql

For example, I get a table as follows

```
user    item    exposure    click   time
a       i1      1           1       2021-09-22 18:58:23
a       i2      1           0       2021-09-22 10:12:32
b       i1      1           0       2021-09-22 08:15:36
b       i2      1           1       2021-09-22 08:10:36
b       i2      1           1       2021-09-22 08:00:02
c       i1      1           0       2021-09-22 07:55:02
a       i1      1           0       2021-09-22 07:45:06
a       i2      1           1       2021-09-22 07:40:02
a       i3      1           0       2021-09-22 07:37:02
a       i1      1           1       2021-09-22 07:35:02
```

I want to know how to get the count and rate of times the same item was exposed by the same user within two hours of clicking on an item as follows.
`re_exposure_cnt` is a count number that a user clicks on the same item and exposure to him again in 2 hours.
`re_exposure_rate` is a rate that a user clicks on the same item and exposure to him again in 2 hours.
`total_sample_cnt` is a total number that a user clicks on the same item.

```
user    item    re_exposure_cnt     re_exposure_rate    total_sample_cnt
a       i1      1                   0.333               3
a       i2      0                   0                   0
a       i3      0                   0                   0          
b       i1      0                   0                   0
b       i2      1                   0.5                 2  
c       i1      0                   0                   0
```

Comment: Not sure how total_sample_cnt =3 for (a,  i1)? 1+0+1

Comment: @Serg `total_sample_cnt` means that the sample number of same user and same item

Comment: @BowenPeng but user a, item i1 only has two rows with click=1 - how is this 3?

Comment: "total_sample_cnt is a total number that a user clicks" and column "click=0" is misleading .  My guess `total_sample_cnt` is a total number of  rows grouped by user + item.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.